# How do you claim the participation reward for Global Link Online Competitions?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon, pokemon-global-link

I participated in the recent *Battle For Alola* online competition, doing the three battles necessary to count as participation and be eligible for the 50 BP participation reward.

How do I claim this reward? I believe in the previous generation, you would receive a code to enter, but [this](https://3ds.pokemon-gl.com/information/13d434f3-6fb6-4a12-8b9c-72f096dc0ce1) says to receive the reward via Game Sync. I've performed a Game Sync but have not received the reward.

(note this is about Online Competitions specifically, not Global Missions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on how it worked in gen 6, you have to wait until the competition is over. After that, sometimes even 10 days after the end, participation rewards will be distributed.

As of 22-12-2016, the participation reward has been distributed.

Comment: The competition is over (it ended a couple of days ago) and the rankings have been published - I achieved a lofty 23,522nd place. There's a news item on global link added today (linked in the question) to announce that the results are in, which states to use Game Sync to receive your reward

Comment: @Kai I'm afraid all you can do is wait, distribution was sometimes slow in XYORAS as well.

Comment: @Kai It should be available now.

Comment: Great thanks. The crux of this is to not assume the prize will go up immediately after the end of the competition or after rankings. It can take some time before prizes are distributed.

Answer (score 1):

To receive your participation reward, you need to connect to the [Global Link](https://3ds.pokemon-gl.com/) website, and then to the competition reward page (for instance, [there for *Battle For Alola*](https://3ds.pokemon-gl.com/present/04de7f58-5bd9-4b2a-9c2d-47d43bcd2bcf)). You will see a special code that you need to keep with you.

Power up your game, and go to the Mystery Gift function in the main menu. Select "Receive Via Code", and then enter the code that you found on the Global Link website. You then just have to go to any Pokémon Center and get your prize.